# DRF PrimaryRelatedField when write and NestedSerializer when read?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a nested serializer. I need `ProfileSerializer` to return full related `Project` object for get requests and consider only id switching (changing current) like with relatedPrimaryField behaiviour for post/put requests on `ProfileSerializer`. any solutions on how to achieve this ?

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current = ProjectSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('function', 'current')
```

Answer (score 7):

As Linova mentioned, the easiest way to solve this issue without using a third-party library is to declare two separate fields in your serializer. Your nested serializer `current` would stay the same, but you would add a new `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` serializer.  The nested serializer should be read only, but the related field would not be read only.  I normally name the related field `<field>_id` by convention.

In GET requests, both the nested serializer and the `id` field will be returned, but for PUT or POST requests only the `<field>_id` needs to be specified.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True)
    current_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Projects.objects.all(), source='current')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('function', 'current', 'current_id')
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need the `read_only=True` on the `ProjectSerializer`?

Answer (score 3):

The most consistent way I usually advice is to mark all the nested serializer (`ProjectSerializer` in this case) as read_only and add the `id` field as `read_only=False`

You'll therefore have consistence between the list/retrieve and creation/updates.

Comment: How would you call that field (current_id) ? do you think there is no cleaner way to achieve this like adding an attribute to the nested serializer field telling them to switch to priamryrelatedfield when needed ?

Comment: Yes this can be have a different behavior for reading and writing. iirc, there's a third party package for that (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/third-party-packages/) however we advice not to to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: @Linovia "not to avoid inconsistencies". Upvote for triple negative.

Comment: you could override to_representation and replace 'current' with the serialized version you want