# Django rest framework nested serializer create method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a nested serializer, when I try to post data in it it keeps on displaying either the foreign key value cannot be null or dictionary expected. I have gone through various similar questions and tried the responses but it is not working for me. Here are the models

```
##CLasses
class Classes(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['class_code']
##Streams
class Stream(models.Model):
    stream_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    classes = models.ForeignKey(Classes,related_name="classes",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stream_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stream_name']
```

Here is the view

```
class StreamViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stream.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StreamSerializer
```

Here is the serializer class

```
class StreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # classesDetails = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    classes = ClassSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Stream
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self,validated_data):
        classes = Classes.objects.get(id=validated_data["classes"])
        return Stream.objects.create(**validated_data, classes=classes)
    # def perfom_create(self,serializer):
    #     serializer.save(classes=self.request.classes)
    #depth = 1
    # def get_classesDetails(self, obj):
    #     clas = Classes.objects.get(id=obj.classes)
    #     classesDetails =  ClassSerializer(clas).data
    #     return classesDetails
```

I have tried several ways of enabling the create method but like this displays an error `{"classes":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}}`. Any contribution would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very common situation when developing APIs with DRF.

#### The problem

Before DRF reaches the `create()` method, it validates the input, which I assume has a form similar to

```
{
   "classes": 3,
   "stream_name": "example"
}
```

This means that, since it was specified that

```py
classes = ClassSerializer()
```

DRF is trying to build the `classes` dictionary from the integer. Of course, this will fail, and you can see that from the error dictionary

```py
{"classes":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}}
```

### Solution 1 (requires a new writable field `{field_name}_id`)

A possible solution is to set `read_only=True` in your `ClassSerializer`, and *use an alternative name for the field when writing*, it's common to use `{field_name}_id`. That way, the validation won't be done. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833368/drf-primaryrelatedfield-when-write-and-nestedserializer-when-read) for more details.

```py
class StreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  classes = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Stream
    fields = (
      'pk',
      'stream_name',
      'classes',
      'created_date',
      'classes_id',
    )
    extra_kwargs = {
      'classes_id': {'source': 'classes', 'write_only': True},
    }
```

This is a clean solution but requires changing the user API. In case that's not an option, proceed to the next solution.

### Solution 2 (requires overriding `to_internal_value`)

Here we [override the `to_internal_value` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_internal_valueself-data). This is where the nested `ClassSerializer` is throwing the error. To avoid this, we set that field to `read_only` and manage the validation and parsing in the method.

Note that since we're not declaring a `classes` field in the writable representation, the default action of `super().to_internal_value` is to ignore the value from the dictionary.

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class StreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  classes = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)

  def to_internal_value(self, data):
      classes_pk = data.get('classes')
      internal_data = super().to_internal_value(data)
      try:
        classes = Classes.objects.get(pk=classes_pk)
      except Classes.DoesNotExist:
          raise ValidationError(
            {'classes': ['Invalid classes primary key']},
            code='invalid',
          )
      internal_data['classes'] = classes
      return internal_data

  class Meta:
    model = Stream
    fields = (
      'pk',
      'stream_name',
      'classes',
      'created_date',
    )
```

With this solution you can use the same field name for both reading and writing, but the code is a bit messy.

#### Additional notes

- You're using the `related_name` argument incorrectly, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django). It's the other way around,

```py
classes = models.ForeignKey(
  Classes,
  related_name='streams',
  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

In this case it should be `streams`.

Comment: I have tried this and it is still displaying an error `{"classes_id":["This field is required."]}`

Comment: @Andrew Just updated the answer to include a method that doesn't require a change of field name

Answer (score 1):

**Kevin Languasco** describes the behaviour of the `create` method quite well and his solutions are valid ones. I would add a variation to solution 1:

```
class StreamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classes = ClassSerializer(read_only=True)
    classes_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    def create(self,validated_data):
      return Stream.objects.create(**validated_data, classes=classes)

    class Meta:
      model = Stream
      fields = (
        'pk',
        'stream_name',
        'classes',
        'classes_id',
        'created_date',
    )
```

The serializer will work without overriding the `create` method, but you can still do so if you want to as in your example.

Pass the value `classes_id` in the body of your POST method, not `classes`. When deserializing the data, the validation will skip `classes` and will check `classes_id` instead.

When serializing the data (when you perform a GET request, for example), `classes` will be used with your nested dictionary and `classes_id` will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this issue in such a way,

**Serializer class**

```
# Classes serializer
class ClassesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Classes
        fields = '__all__'

# Stream serializer
class StreamSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    classes = ClassesSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Stream
        fields = '__all__'
```

**View**

```
# Create Stream view
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_stream(request):
    classes_id = request.data['classes']  # or however you are sending the id
    serializer = StreamSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        classes_instance = get_object_or_404(Classes, id=classes_id)
        serializer.save(classes=classes_instance)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```