# Django Rest Framework - get related FK object for use in template; POST not working now?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I've got a form up and working with a Vue frontend and DRF backend. It's a form for adding (creating) a new model - and has a dropdown of the related models that are FK to the model being created.

I need to access attributes of the selected FK item.

My serializers look like this:

```
class SubdomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subdomain
        fields = [
            "id",
            "domain",
            "short_description",
            "long_description",
            "character_code",
        ]

    # def get_absolute_url(self, obj):
    #     return obj.get_absolute_url()


class EvidenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    updated_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    created_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    updated_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Evidence
        fields = "__all__"
```

The form is to create a new 'Evidence' item, and the 'Subdomain' is a dropdown on the form that contains all related subdomains.

The models look like this:

```
class Subdomain(CreateUpdateMixin):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    long_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    character_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Evidence(CreateUpdateMixin, CreateUpdateUserMixin, SoftDeletionModel):
    subdomain = models.ForeignKey(Subdomain, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        Evaluation, related_name="evidences", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

In my form, I just want to include the `short_description` of each `subdomain` when the user chooses it from the dropdown - I may also want to use the `long_description` as well.

Here is the bit in the form where I render the dropdown:

```
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                            <label class="" for="subdomain">Subdomain</label>
                            <select name="subdomain" id="subdomain" class="form-control" v-model="element.subdomain">
                                <option v-for="choice in subdomains" :value="choice.id" >{{ choice.character_code }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small" v-if="element.subdomain">
                            <!-- THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO DISPLAY THE SHORT DESCRIPTION FOR THE CHOICE IN THE DROPDOWN -->
                            {{ choice.short_description }}
                        </div>
```

The Form Data looks like this when I POST:

```
evaluation: 2037
subdomain: 448
comments: Test comments to add to the subdomain
published: true
csrfmiddlewaretoken: 382796ryfuasiodfgyhakljyht37yaisdfaslk3r
```

Things I have tried - some of which worked for display purposes but seem to have broken the form/POST:

- Adding `depth=1` to the Meta of the `EvidenceSerializer`, which worked but made the form no longer submit appropriately. I think it's because it wanted the entire subdomain instead of just the ID? I couldn't get it working - the subdomain always threw an error.
- Adding the following to my `EvidenceSerializer`, which again seemed to break the POST operation, it would cause the subdomain dropdown to throw an error.

```
subdomain = SubdomainSerializer(read_only=True)
```

Using both of those methods above the dropdown doesn't recognize the `subdomain_id` being selected and both end up throwing this error behind the scenes:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'subdomain_id', table 'local_app.dbo.myapp_evidence'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Any advice on how to proceed would be fantastic.

TLDR; Need to be able to access attributes on a FK relationship for a dropdown using DRF, and be able to submit that item in a form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42859563/6759844

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880463/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-create-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bdbd for pointing me in the right direction.

For anyone curious, I resolved it using those links - turns out I needed to change my serializers a little bit:

```
class SubdomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subdomain
        fields = [
            "id",
            "domain",
            "short_description",
            "long_description",
            "character_code",
        ]


class EvidenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    updated_by = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    created_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    updated_by_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # add the 'subdomain' as read only - but with all the attributes
    subdomain = SubdomainSerializer(read_only=True)
    # add the 'subdomain_id' as a PrimaryKeyRelatedField with the source being the subdomain
    subdomain_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Subdomain.objects.all(), source="subdomain"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Evidence
        fields = "__all__"
```

Then I updated the HTML a little bit:

```
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <label class="" for="subdomain_id">Subdomain</label>
                    <select name="subdomain_id" id="subdomain" class="form-control" v-model="element.subdomain">
                        <option v-for="choice in subdomains" :value="choice" >{{ choice.character_code }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="small" v-if="element.subdomain_id">
                    {{ element.subdomain.short_description }}
                </div>
```

Then in the ajax call I simply assign the `subdomain_id` to the `subdomain.id`

```
        data: {
            evaluation : evaluationId,
            subdomain_id : vm.element.subdomain.id,
            comments : vm.element.comments,
            published: vm.element.published,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: vm.sharedStore.state.csrftoken,
        },
```